# Android app for Magento store using REST or SOAP?

Tags: soap, rest-api

Hi there i want to know which service to use for making a mobile application for magento does it have to be rest or soap i want to have complete functionality as that of my website inside mobile app.any type of personal experience and help is much appreciated

Comment: dont tell me duplicates i have watched nearly all of them none of them answer the above question

Comment: Just try to connect Magento thru Oauth and access the resources by using RESTful web services.
`http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_configuration.html`

Comment: but the functionality is not completely provided by the rest api:

Comment: Magento REST API allows managing a number of features, namely:

Managing customers.
Managing customer addresses.
Managing products.
Retrieving sales orders.
Managing inventory.